# How does one view an html project while working on it in Caret text editor?

Tags: python, html, css, caret, chromebook

I actually have multiple questions about web development with a Chromebook. my apologies if this is long. So far, i have very little knowledge in HTML and CSS and am looking to expand (curious about python currently), but it seems to be very uncut with a Chromebook and highly confusing at times. so here are my questions:

1. Is Caret a good text editor for Chromebook? And are there any tutorials on how to use Caret or what it is fully capable of?
2. Is python downloadable on a Chromebook, and what are some good places for a beginner to learn how to use python?
3. Are there any ways to turn an html document into an actual website, like one you can view on any device with a domain name and all that?

Thank you to anybody who can answer these questions or any information regarding. There isn't much on all this online that i have been able to find. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you've not found an answer yet, I might be able to help on questions 1 & 3...

#### Q1

Caret is the best text editor that you can run directly on a Chromebook (as opposed to using an online editor like Cloud9, which is great but more complicated to setup). I've used it for a couple of years and love it.

The best place to find advice on using it is on the [creator's website](https://thomaswilburn.net/caret/). It's not particularly complete but covers most things. And anyhow, it's basically a pretty simple app.

#### Q3

However... it is an editor, not an 'IDE' (integrated development environment) - which is why you can't work out how to see an HTML doc as an actual webpage. The functionality isn't built into Caret.

The good news is that there is a very simple way to do this. Get the Chrome extension 'Web Server for Chrome' - [available here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb). This allows you to choose the folder where you've saved the HTML (and any CSS / JavaScript) and gives you a link to view it in the browser. It's dead easy!

#### ...and Q2

Coming back to q2 about Python. I've not tried myself but I would guess it's possible. This is more challenging as you need to use the command line and configure your Chromebook. If you follow the instructions on [this page](https://blog.lessonslearned.org/building-a-more-secure-development-chromebook/) (jump down to the section called 'The Termux Secret Sauce') that did the trick very neatly for me. You need to use an SSH client and the [Chrome extension by Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd) is very simple to use.
Once setup, you can then just Google instructions on running Python on Linux.

Hope all that helps.

PS if you get into more coding, the benefits of an IDE are significant. Just the autocompletion and code formatting alone make life much easier than with Caret. I used Cloud9, which is part of AWS. You can get a free-tier EC2 virtual machine to run it off, but there's some faffing around to be able to view webpages from your browser.